# Shell Script: Iterating over array of json

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array of jsons which I need to iterate over. I do a curl call and get this result and need to process it for something.
The array looks like this:

```
 [
{"id": "f0345a01", "name": "scala1"},
 {"id": "6f907cf", "name": "scala2"}, 
{"id": "d887f61", "name": "scala3"}, 
{"id": "5d07fca", "name": "scala5"}, 
{"id": "94ddaa", "name": "scala12"}
]
```

I need to get the id's from this array. 
I could not find any way to do so. I tried this following another stackoverflow question:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}" 
do
    echo "$i"

done
```

Comment: The fact that Bash variables use curly braces doesn't mean they are JSON. You need a program that is capable of properly parsing JSON-formatted data.

Comment: You might find something like https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ useful.

Comment: Seconding jq. A filter would look as simple as `jq '.[].id'`.

Comment: You skipped the step where you (think you) stored the output of `curl` in `arr` in a useful way.

Comment: @mustaccio - good point, had not realised that. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @ccarton - Thanks for the link, Yes, it seems useful. Will be using it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - Yes, checked that. Thanks

Comment: @chepner - Did not get your point. Am just storing the result returned by the curl call in a variable. Should I be doing something else?

Comment: Probably; *how* are you setting the variable? For instance, `arr=$(curl ...)` would be wrong; are you doing something more complicated?

Comment: @chepner - No, I was doing something like a= curl -X .... , And was able to do the rest of the process by the suggested answers. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to obtain the ids:

```
curl http://... | jq -r '.[].id'
```

You can pipe that into a bash `while` loop if you want to perform further processing:

```
curl http://... | jq -r '.[].id' | while read id ; do
    do_something "${id}"
done
```

Comment: this worked for me when others wouldn't, thanks. could you explain the 2nd pipe clause and the 'read' ?

Answer (score 2):

### Use a PCRE-Compatible Grep

If you don't want to do a full parse with jq (which is probably the right thing to do), then you can grep for your lines. There are all sorts of problems with this, though, including shell quoting issues, inconsistent whitespace in your corpus, no guarantee that you won't have nested objects, and so forth.

If you just want the id attributes, use a grep with PCRE support such as *pcregrep*. To keep the regular expression simple, you can then strip the surrounding quotes with *tr*. For example:

```
$ pcregrep -o '"id": \K"[[:xdigit:]]{7,8}"' <<< "$result" | tr -d \"
f0345a01
6f907cf
d887f61
5d07fca
```

Note that this is very dependent on your corpus, and on the presence of a non-standard grep, but it's still useful if you know your data and just want a list of IDs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're curl does get you this formatted list

```
[
{"id": "f0345a01", "name": "scala1"},
{"id": "6f907cf", "name": "scala2"}, 
{"id": "d887f61", "name": "scala3"}, 
{"id": "5d07fca", "name": "scala5"}, 
{"id": "94ddaa", "name": "scala12"}
]
```

Then just doing something like:

```
curl -s "your_link" | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '",'
```

OUTPUT:

```
cat sample | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '","'

f0345a01
6f907cf
d887f61
5d07fca
94ddaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following "dirty hack":

```
ids=$(echo "${arr}" | tr -s '\n' ' ' | tr -s ',' '\n' \
    | grep '"id"\s*:' | cut -d '"' -f 4)
for i in ${ids}
do
    echo "===> $i"
done
```

As you can see it does not parse the array, but rather assumes the structure you provided and just grep/cut the array to get the ids.

- tr -s '\n' ' ' substitutes all newlines to spaces, so it will correctly handle the case when "id" and the value are separated with a newline
- tr -s ',' '\n' substitutes all commas to newlines, so we have one key-value per line
- grep '"id"\s*:' greps all lines with "id" keys
- finally cut -d '"' -f 4 uses quotation marks as a delimiter and cuts the value

Answer (score 1):

could use awk in this specific case (allowing other manip also if needed)

```
 YourCurlStream | awk 'NF>1{gsub( /[":,{}]/, "");$0=$0;print $2 }'
```